# Display TimeStamp with Charts API Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I am trying to take a timestamp saved in Firestore and display it in my app using ios Charts. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Charts
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseAuth

class YearChartViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate {

private var timeRetrieval = [timeData]()

var barChart = BarChartView()

lazy var companyUser = ""

@IBOutlet weak var localeIdLabel: UILabel!




private var timeDataCollection: CollectionReference!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    barChart.delegate = self
    
    localeIdLabel.text = companyUser
    
    timeDataCollection = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(companyUser ).collection("time_data")

    
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    barChart.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    barChart.center = view.center
    
    view.addSubview(barChart)
    
    var entries = [BarChartDataEntry]()
    
    for i in 0..<timeRetrieval.count {
    
        let formatter = DateFormatter();
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
        
    timeDataCollection.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                    if let err = error {
                        debugPrint("Error fetching docs: \(err)")
                    } else {
                     guard let snap = querySnapshot else { return }
                     for document in snap.documents {
                         let FirebaseData = document.data()
                        let tiempoEs = formatter.string(from: FirebaseData["timestamp"] as? Date ?? Date())
                        let documentIdThird = document.documentID
                         
                       
                        
                        
                        let newTimeRetrieval = timeData(timeContinuum: tiempoEs, documentId3: documentIdThird)
                         self.timeRetrieval.append(newTimeRetrieval)

        
        
                        entries.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(timeRetrieval[i]), y: Double(timeRetrieval[i])))
                     }
                     }
        
    let set = BarChartDataSet(entries: entries
    )
    
    set.colors = ChartColorTemplates.joyful()
    
    let data = BarChartData(dataSet: set)
    
                self.barChart.data = data
}


}
}
}
```

"timeRetrieval" is taken from a class called "timeData":

```
 import Foundation
 import Firebase

 class timeData {
   var timeContinuum: String!
   var documentId3: String!




init(timeContinuum: String, documentId3: String) {
    
    self.timeContinuum = timeContinuum
    self.documentId3 = documentId3
    
    
   
    
}
}
```

When I try to the value "timeRetreival[i]" in the first block of code into a Double, it says that "Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'timeData' conform to 'BinaryInteger'". If I don't wrap it into a Double value, it reads "Cannot convert value of type 'timeData' to expected argument type 'Double'". What would anyone suggest to solve this?

Comment: Let's split the steps: `let timeData = timeRetrieval[I]`; how do you get an `Double` from that? It doesn't make sense. From `timeContinuum` ? But it's a String, so need conversion from it? Also, I guess that `getDocuments()` is async, so the loop might be wrong.

Comment: So timeData is of type date, I tried to convert it to string because I thought it would be more easily converted to Double from there. Since it’s a timeStamp it can’t be a Double, so I’m wondering if there is a workaround? Like make the dates part of the x axis label and just display data of how many times someone “checks in” at a specific day?